# TYPO3 8.7 - Link Target ist missing in navigation for page typ external URL

Tags: typo3

After update from TYPO3 7.6.16 to 8.7 in my navigation (TMENU) the target _blank is no longer output for pages of typ external URL. In page properties the target flag _blank is entered. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, working for me:

```
lib.mainmenuu = HMENU
lib.mainmenuu {
    special = directory
    special.value = 1
    1=TMENU
    1.wrap=<ul>|</ul>
    1.NO {
        # do not create a link here else there are double <a> tags
        doNotLinkIt = 1
        wrapItemAndSub=<li>|</li>
        stdWrap.cObject = CASE
        stdWrap.cObject {
        key.field = doktype
        default = TEXT
        default {
            field = title
            typolink.parameter.field = uid
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        }
       # 3 = external url
       3 = TEXT
       3 {
           field = title
           typolink.parameter.field = url
           typolink.extTarget = _blank
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Here, use your news detail page id instead of 27. this will override default page title with current detail news title.

Comment: My pleasure, @intermb. Have fun..:)